# How to use the domReady requireJS plugin correctly

Tags: javascript, requirejs, domready

Here is my main.js before using domReady:

```
require.config({
  paths : {
      loader : 'libs/backbone/loader',
      jQuery : 'libs/jquery/jquery-module',
      Underscore : 'libs/underscore/underscore-module',
      Backbone : 'libs/backbone/backbone-module',
      templates : '../Templates'
  }
});

require([ 'app' ], function(app) {
  app.initialize();
});
```

And app.js:

```
define([ 'jQuery', 'Underscore', 'Backbone', 'router',
    'services/Initializers/MainFrameInitializer',
    'services/Initializers/FlowsViewsInitializer',
    'services/Initializers/EditModuleInitializer',
    'services/Sandboxes/ModulesNavigationSandbox',
    'services/Sandboxes/ApplicationStateSandbox', 'DataModel/Constants' ],
    function($, _, Backbone, Router, MainFrameInitializer,
        FlowsViewsInitializer, EditModuleInitializer, ModulesNavigationSandbox,
        ApplicationStateSandbox, Constants) {
      var initialize = function() {
        // Pass in our Router module and call it's initialize function
        MainFrameInitializer.initialize();
        FlowsViewsInitializer.initialize();
        EditModuleInitializer.initialize();
        ApplicationStateSandbox.startCheckStatus();
        ModulesNavigationSandbox.navigate(Constants.Modules.Home);
        // Router.initialize();
      };

      return {
        initialize : initialize
      };
    });
```

All works fine until I [optimize](http://requirejs.org/docs/optimization.html) the project. I have figured out, that the script starts to run before the DOM is ready, something that was not true before the optimization. Anyway, I wish to use the [domReady](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#pageload) plugin to make sure the DOM is loaded first.

But, apparently, I have no idea how to do it correctly. Here is the new version of main.js:

```
require.config({
  paths : {
      loader : 'libs/backbone/loader',
      jQuery : 'libs/jquery/jquery-module',
      Underscore : 'libs/underscore/underscore-module',
      Backbone : 'libs/backbone/backbone-module',
      templates : '../Templates'
  }
});

require([ 'domReady', 'app' ], function(domReady, app) {
  domReady(app.initialize);
});
```

Very neat and very wrong, because `app` is loaded in parallel with `domReady` before the DOM is ready.

How do I fix it?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

I think I have understood our problem. The constructor functions of the `app` dependencies should not run any DOM dependent code. They should just return functions, capturing the DOM dependent logic. That logic should be executed from `app.initialize`, which is guaranteed to be run when the DOM is ready.

Comment: Why is it wrong for `domReady` and `app` to be loaded in parallel? You only actually invoke code from `app` when the DOM is ready. Or have I misunderstood?

Comment: It is possible that it is me who misunderstands how the stuff works. Loading `app` involves loading all of the app dependencies (and there are quite a few), then these dependencies are invoked and the results are passed to the app factory method, which returns the `app` itself. If I understand it correctly, the dependencies of `app` are executed in parallel with `domReady`, which means they may run before the DOM is fully loaded.

Comment: Nothing *runs* unless your factory function that you pass to `define()` actually runs code. Usually, the factory function just creates an object with methods that can be called *at some point in the future* (you have done this). So even though a call to `define()` will run the factory function, you only do *real* app work when you want to. Like you have done by passing `app.initialize` to the `domReady` function. It seems fine to me.

Comment: I have edited my post. Is that what you mean?

Answer (score 7):

Perhaps I am missing something, but wouldn't you make your life a lot easier by doing:

```
require(['jQuery', 'app' ], function(jQuery, app) {
  jQuery(function ($) {
    app.initialize();
  });
});
```

in your `main.js`?

Comment: We are using jQuery, but you cannot use it like that straight ahead, because jQuery does not define itself as a module in the requireJS sense of it. It requires certain preparations first and we do them. Also, notice that `app` does depend on `jQuery`, it is its first dependency.

Comment: jQuery *is* AMD compliant since iirc 1.7. You can always use a loader if you depend on some previous version. Your app and main both depending on jQuery is not going to violate anything (jquery is still loaded once) but it will allow you to not add another plugin.

Comment: OK, but this scheme still demands that the factory methods of the modules upon which `app` depends do not manipulate DOM, because `app` dependencies are resolved and invoked in parallel with the loading of jQuery. The original issue remains. But it seems that I have figured out what is the catch here - see the edit of my post.

Comment: There is nothing that demands you to not use jQuery/manipulate your dom. It's just plain simple js. It's fine to add jQuery as a dependency to your main if you want to use its ready().

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, jQuery will define itself as a module and the above code will be valid. Prior to 1.7 you could use require-jquery.js to load jQuery from require js and to define it as a module.

Comment: Not clear what happened on the jQuery front. The site docs.jquery.com returns "NO PAGE TEXT MATCHES" when searching for requirejs. requirejs provides a version of require with jquery 1.8 bundled as a module - http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html

Comment: @widged: Search for jQuery + AMD. Require.js is just one of more AMD-loaders, which all of tries to follow the CommonJS standard for AMD-loading. http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/7102

Answer (score 7):

By requiring the app from inside the domReady callback function, you should be able to require the domReady module, and then the app module synchronously.

```
define(['require', 'domReady'], function(require, domReady) {
  domReady(function() {
    require(['app'], function(app) {
      app.initialize();
    });
  });
});
```

Answer (score 3):

If you follow the doc at: http://requirejs.org/docs/jquery.html, you will be invited to embed a require-jquery library in the head of your document:

```
<script data-main="main" src="libs/require-jquery.js"></script>
```

However, if you look at the source for the example, made available on [github](https://github.com/jrburke/require-jquery), you will see that 'require-jquery.js' is generated by simple concatenation of the require lib file and the jquery lib file:

```
 cat require.js jquery.js > ../jquery-require-sample/webapp/scripts/require-jquery.js
```

That means that you could replace the script embed in the head part with the following script embeds anywhere in your document (for instance at the very bottom of it).

```
  <script src="libs/require.js"></script>
  <script src="libs/jquery-1.8.0.js"></script>
  <script>require(["main"]);</script>
```

Because the jquery lib defines itself as a module with:

```
  define( "jquery", [], function () { return jQuery; } );
```

You can thereafter use jquery as a require reference in any of your script. For instance:

```
  require(["jquery"], function($) { }
```